# Is there an easy way to drag items around in a ListView to change their order?

Tags: android, user-interface, listview

Let's say I have a ListView of items:

- Cat
- Dog
- Mouse

And these are bound to the ListView via an adapter to a database.

What I want to be able to do is to be able to re-order the list view,. For example I want to somehow drag "Mouse" up to the top of the list above "Cat".  Once I have an order set, I then want to "save" the list and its order back to the database.

Is there any way to do this?  Has someone made such a custom ListView that I could use?  The only alternative I can think of is to long press on a list view item and have a "Move up by one", "Move to top", etc. context menu that moves items around in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Android's music application does that with the playlist.
Check it's source code [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=summary).

Comment: I have that stuff packaged up as a reusable component: http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist -- note that an update should get pushed out in the next 24-48 hours.

Comment: @CommonsWare: what are you going to add?

Comment: the existing project does not so much "add" as "tease the code out of the tie-in to the Music app so it's reusable". The pending updates are simply reflecting a reworking of the parcel system to use Android library projects, plus a bit of cleanup on how some of the custom attributes are named.

Comment: @CommonsWare Nice, I'll look at your component soon.  I'm in no rush for this particular piece of the puzzle, so I can wait for your update.